# In Vue JS, how can I make my APIService.js class globally available to components without requiring individual components to import it?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

Almost all of my components require some kind of interaction with my apiservice.js class, which imports Axios and makes appropriate http requests depending on the method called. I know this isn't normally recommended, but, in every one of my components, I have the following:

```
import {APIService} from '../store/APIService.js';
const apiService = new APIService();
```

My APIService.js looks roughly like this (trimmed down for simplicity):

```
import axios from 'axios';
const API_URL = 'http://myserver:82/services/locationmanagement';

export class APIService{

constructor(){
}

getLocations() {
    const url = `${API_URL}/api/locations/`;
    return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data);
}

saveLocation(location) {
    let url = `${API_URL}/api/locations/`;
    let id = location.id;
    let httpMethod = 'post';

    if(id > 0 ) {
        httpMethod = 'put';
        url = `${API_URL}/api/locations/${id}`;
    }

    let options = {
        method: httpMethod,
        url: url,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: location
    }

    return axios(options);
   }

}
```

I would prefer if this were somehow made available to the global Vue instance and my components could access it somehow.

I believe this needs to be implemented in some form within my **main.js** file, possibly via Vue.use, but I'm still unsure of how to implement this even after reviewing the docs.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use Vuex, and make these store actions instead of using a class.  Also, you are instantiating your class multiple times needlessly.  You could instantiate it once in the external file and export the instance instead of the class itself.

Comment: <-- mind blown! .... i've been using Vuex actions ubiqutiously because "that's what I read", but the implementation was never different than a mutator. I knew i could put asynchronous code in the Actions, but wasn't sure why I would do that...Now I know.

Comment: You can think of a global store as a good place for any functionality-- including both data and methods (i.e. state and actions)-- that isn't strictly connected to a component.  General app data and loading processes can be a good example of that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on moving the saveLocation functionality into an action and storing the result be it success or failure in a "serviceResult" value in the store. I have a DIV in App.vue that gets displayed so long as "serviceResult" has a value. I'm hoping I can use this as a sort of universal "Errors" & "Messages" section in my application without making each component manage that themselves. Furthermore, this would open a means for me to add some kind of logging in the Store which remove more ubiquitous functionality from the components. It's not working quite yet, but I think it will.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Vuejs Plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) import it into `main.js`, and call it there with `Vue.use(myservice)`

**EDIT:**

Per comment, one way is to add the plugin to the Vue prototype. For example, an axios wrapper could be defined as

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {

  install:function(Vue,options) {

    Vue.prototype.$dataservice = axios.create({...})
    ...
```

then it can be called from a component like other global vue functions, e.g., `$refs`, `$set`, `$emit`:

```
 ...
 this.$dataservice.get(...)
 // or
 this.$dataservice.post(...)
 ...
```

With a data service api, if using Vuex, it may be useful to use this primarily in "actions".

Comment: How do you call your plugin within components?